# How to get last Git tag matching regex criteria

Tags: regex, git, tags, find, tagging

I need Git command to **get/find last tag starting with** 'v' to get last versioning commit (I am using tags with v letter at the beginning to tag next application version (**example: v0.9.1beta**).

Is there any way to do it?

Comment: Can you just use `git describe`?

Comment: Yep .. git describe --match v* was what I needed. Thank You.

Comment: Can someone please edit the title, as for this it is not needed to really use a regex. Also all the answer just use the match and "glob" pattern. thx.

Comment: I'm looking for the answer to the question in the title (regex not glob)!

Comment: @RobFisher Maybe add a bounty ;)

Comment: @RobFisher [There](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42131335/321973) you go

Comment: @d4Rk Renaming the title would be an option. I [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42131335/321973) instead...

Answer (score 102, accepted):

Use the following command:

```
git describe --tags --match="v[0-9]*" HEAD
```

It will also modify the version if you did something with the source tree since your last versioned tag.

**NOTE:** `--match` accepts a glob, *not* a regex, and therefore the command shown may match other tags, e.g. `v1234_this_matches_too`.

Comment: If you want just the tag use the "short output" with `--abbrev=0`.

Comment: The [`git describe` doc](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-describe) says that `--match` takes a glob, not a regex.

Comment: @CraigMcQueen that is a glob, and that's why it is working and filters out `v1.0.0` and not only `v1234`. I added a note to clarify that.

Comment: In case one really needs a RegEx, I added [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42131335/321973)

Comment: The question is asking to find the last *tag* matching the pattern. So I think `--tags` must be added at the end. Otherwise only annotated tags will be shown.

Answer (score 19):

```
git tag -n v*
```

`-n` means `--list` is implied.

Comment: It lists all tag matching criteria. I need only last one, so git describe --match v*. Anyway thanks for hints as tags and describe command are linked together on the git manual pages.

Comment: this worked for me, as `git describe` wasn't flexible enough (returned an ugly tag, and wasn't always the most recent).  `git tag --list --sort=-version:refname "v*" | head -n 1`

Answer (score 17):

The problem with using `git describe` as the other answers do is that `git describe` will show you tags that are reachable from HEAD (or the commit you specify.)

Imagine you have 3 tags, v1, v2, and v3. If HEAD is at a point between v2 and v3, `git describe` would return v2 rather than v3.

If you actually want the latest tag, first of all you need annotated tags as lightweight tags have no date metadata.

Then this command will do it:

`git for-each-ref --sort=-taggerdate --count=1  refs/tags/v*`

Answer (score 14):

Also with git describe you could get the latest tag not just reachable from HEAD with :

`git describe --match "v*" --abbrev=0 --tags $(git rev-list --tags --max-count=1)`

Answer (score 8):

[KARASZI István's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3867811/321973) already explains how to find tags matching a *glob*, which is usually fine enough. Should you ever need a real RegEx though:

```bash
for tag in $(git tag | grep YOURREGEX); do
    git describe --tags --long --match="$tag" 2>/dev/null
done | sort -k2 -t"-" | head -n1
```

- If you only want the nearest tag (i.e. what `--abrev=0` would achieve), append `| cut -d"-" -f1`
- If you don't want `--long`'s behaviour of also outputting an *exactly* matching tag including the `-0-hash` part, append `| sed -e's/-0-.*$//'` instead.

The question's example tag would probably use a Regex `^v\d+\.\d+\.\d+\D*$` (though the `\D*$` might be optional).

Comment: ...though this is obviously worse in terms of performance, since `git describe` is run for _each_ tag matching the RegEx.

Comment: For my usecase (see regex) with inconsistent tag naming (with or without prefix) this helped a lot, and only uses one execution of git describe.
`git describe --abbrev=0 --tags --match="*$(git tag | grep -E "^(releases?\/|v)?[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+$" | sed -E 's/.*([0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+)$/\1/' | sort -V -r | head -n 1)"`. Maybe this helps for similar further usecases.

Comment: @qwc thanks, the command helped me to get the latest git tag with certain features.

Comment: @qwc 
thanks, the command is working, but
can you provide us a brief explaination about your command so that we can use in other use cases as well.

Comment: @Madhan I guess my answer deserves an edit when I have some time, please ping me if I forget to do so by next week ;)

Answer (score 8):

While a single pattern `--match "v[0-9]*"` is enough here, know that Git 2.13 (Q2 2017) will improve that:

> "[`git describe`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-describe)" and "[`git name-rev`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-name-rev)" have been taught to take more than one refname patterns to restrict the set of refs to base their naming output on, and also learned to take negative patterns to
> name refs not to be used for naming via their "`--exclude`" option.

See [commit 77d21f2](https://github.com/git/git/commit/77d21f29eaddb1fbe82e013ea42d4e0180bbdda2), [commit 43f8080](https://github.com/git/git/commit/43f8080eaff82e7aedaec5aa3abfd115cf1af695), [commit 96415b4](https://github.com/git/git/commit/96415b49dc4e10b64c014516a3f7cd9a51ed5269), [commit 290be66](https://github.com/git/git/commit/290be6674a4c89594105faa19061523e7380d586), [commit 4a68748](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4a68748893e62d66ebab1591f6da91eeb18d08e9) (18 Jan 2017) by [Jacob Keller (`jacob-keller`)](https://github.com/jacob-keller).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 1b32498](https://github.com/git/git/commit/1b324988ac0fe14d069991736962289a35f15aec), 27 Feb 2017)</sup>

You now can have [**multiple match pattern**](https://github.com/git/git/blob/43f8080eaff82e7aedaec5aa3abfd115cf1af695/Documentation/git-describe.txt#L86-L89):

```
--match <pattern>:
```

> Only consider tags matching the given `glob(7)` pattern,  excluding the "refs/tags/" prefix.
> This can be used to avoid leaking private tags from the repository.
>
> If given multiple times, a list of patterns will be accumulated, and tags matching any of the patterns will be considered.
> Use `--no-match` to clear and reset the list of patterns.

And you have also an [**exclude pattern** (or several) now](https://github.com/git/git/blob/77d21f29eaddb1fbe82e013ea42d4e0180bbdda2/Documentation/git-describe.txt#L91-L99)!

```
--exclude <pattern>::
```

> Do not consider tags matching the given `glob(7)` pattern, excluding the "refs/tags/" prefix.
>
> This can be used to narrow the tag space and  find only tags matching some meaningful criteria.
> If given multiple times, a list of patterns will be accumulated and tags matching any of the patterns will be excluded.
> When combined with `--match` a tag will be considered when it matches at least one `--match` pattern and does not match any of the `--exclude` patterns.
> Use `--no-exclude` to clear and reset the list of patterns.

Answer (score 1):

```
git describe --match v*
```

Use this.

Comment: this will include all the tags starts with `v`, so it'll list all the words not just versions

Answer (score 0):

I use

```
git tag -l --format "%(objecttype) %(refname:short)" --sort=-version:refname --merged HEAD "v*"
```

`git tag` interprets the pattern as glob. So you cannot specify a full blown regex. Just use a minimal glob (v*) or even no glob at all. You will receive more than only one matching tag in sorted order (highest tag version first) and you will be able to regex the output afterwards.

Answer (score -4):

Something more complex would be along the lines of:

```java
/v[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+).*/
```

Comment: Have you looked at all the answers? An example of how to use the above string was already given like: git describe --match "/v[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+).*/" --abbrev=4 HEAD

Comment: That is not working, cause --match parameter only supports glob patterns no regex patterns

Comment: It worked for me, so most likely you are missing something or we have different versions of tools used.